# Get IP Address when testing flask application through nosetests

Tags: python, testing, flask, nosetests, werkzeug

My application depends on `request.remote_addr` which is `None` when i run tests through nosetests which uses `app.test_client().post('/users/login', ....)`.

**How can I emulate an IP (127.0.0.1 works fine) when I run tests?**
I've tried setting environment variables, sent in headers with the post() method and I've digged through nosetests, werkzeugs and flasks documentation but nothing I've tried has worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting (mocking) request headers for Flask app unit test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15278285/setting-mocking-request-headers-for-flask-app-unit-test)

Comment: @Styvane: Uhm, this question is a month older, how is it a duplicate?

Comment: Perhaps I didn't choose the right question but [yes it is possible](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha/147651#147651)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can set options for the underlying Werkzeug environment using [environ_base](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/test/#testing-api):

```
from flask import Flask, request
import unittest

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.testing = True

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return str(request.remote_addr)

class TestApp(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_remote_addr(self):
        c = app.test_client()
        resp = c.get('/', environ_base={'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1'})
        self.assertEqual('127.0.0.1', resp.data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly but having to append that on every single call would get tedious. A friend gave me a solution for fix that changes every call. Posting it as an answer as well.

Comment: +1 This appears to be the way werkzeug intended you to do this and was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Now my tests are passing in instances that needs to have a valid IP. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

A friend gave me this solution, which works across all requests:

```
class myProxyHack(object):

    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        environ['REMOTE_ADDR'] = environ.get('REMOTE_ADDR', '127.0.0.1')
        return self.app(environ, start_response)

app.wsgi_app = myProxyHack(app.wsgi_app)

app.test_client().post(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass a `header` param to the `test_request_context` if you prefer.

Example:

```py
from flask import Flask, request
import unittest

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.testing = True

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return str(request.remote_addr)

class TestApp(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_headers(self):
        user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0"
        ip_address = 127.0.0.1
        headers = {
            'Remote_Addr': ip_address,
            'User_Agent': user_agent
        }

        with self.test_request_context(headers=headers):
            # Do something
            pass
```

This is useful when you need to perform several unit tests using the `request` object in other modules.

See the [test_request_context documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/testing/#other-testing-tricks).