# Setting (mocking) request headers for Flask app unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

Does anyone know of a way to set (mock) the User-Agent of the request object provided by FLask (Werkzeug) during unit testing?

As it currently stands, when I attempt to obtain details such as the request.headers['User-Agent'] a KeyError is raised as the Flask test_client() doesn't set these up. (See partial stack trace below)

When attempting to get the User-Agent from the request object in a Flask project during unit testing, a KeyError is raised.

```
File "/Users/me/app/rest/app.py", line 515, in login
    if request.headers['User-Agent']:
File "/Users/me/.virtualenvs/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 1229, in __getitem__
    return self.environ['HTTP_' + key]
    KeyError: 'HTTP_USER_AGENT'
```

-- UPDATE --

Along with the (accepted) solution below, the environ_base hint lead me to this other [SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872829/get-ip-address-when-testing-flask-application-through-nosetests). The premise of this solution is to create a wrapper class for the Flask app and override the **call** method to automatically set the environment variables. This way, the variables are set for all calls. So, the solution I ended up implementing is creating this proxy class:

```
class FlaskTestClientProxy(object):
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        environ['REMOTE_ADDR'] = environ.get('REMOTE_ADDR', '127.0.0.1')
        environ['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = environ.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT', 'Chrome')
        return self.app(environ, start_response)
```

And then wrapping the WSGI container with that proxy:

```
app.wsgi_app = FlaskTestClientProxy(app.wsgi_app)
test_client = app.test_client()
```

Comment: Your solution does not work for me, while Chris' does. I am using a pytest fixture for testing so that may have something to do with it:

app = create_app(config_class=config.TestConfig);
testing_client = app.test_client();
ctx = app.test_request_context() ;
ctx.push();
yield testing_client;  
ctx.pop()

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to pass in `environ_base` when you call `get()` or `post()`.  E.g.,

```
client = app.test_client()
response = client.get('/your/url/', 
                      environ_base={'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Chrome, etc'})
```

Then your `request.user_agent` should be whatever you pass in, and you can access it via `request.headers['User-Agent']`.

See http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/test/#testing-api for more info.

Comment: Thanks! Although I ended up using the solution I included in my original question above, this would have worked perfectly fine as well.

Comment: Nice one, I think that solution is far more elegant if you need to set those environment variables on all your tests... In fact I think you've convinced me to change my Flask apps to do the same thing!

Comment: This also works in `app.test_request_context` (maybe useful if you're trying to write unit tests instead of integration tests)

Comment: How do we override 'Host' i.e. ```request.host``` using this method?

Comment: RE: @toszter -- Pass in ```headers``` containing a list of tuples e.g. ```headers=[('Host','unit-tester'),]``` -- ```environ_override``` doesn't work, nor did ```environ_base```. :(

Comment: There are some inconsistencies around the expected format of these keys. AFAICT `HTTP_USER_AGENT` is a Flask special case that uses all underscores, and everything else uses either e.g. `HTTP_CONTENT-TYPE` or `CONTENT_TYPE`. Because of the way the keys are updated, a different tuple is created for each key format, so you may need to one or the other depending on context. e.g. to override `Content-Length` you must use `CONTENT_LENGTH`, not `HTTP_CONTENT-LENGTH`. See https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/810cd659153a7c9923e2557a00c587c8bc77d74a/src/werkzeug/test.py#L763-L817

Answer (score 8):

Even though what @chris-mckinnel wrote works, I wouldn't opt to use `environ_base` in this case.

You can easily do something as shown below:

```
with app.test_request_context('url', headers={'User-Agent': 'Your value'}):
    pass
```

This should do the job and at the same time it keeps your code explicit - explicit is better than implicit.

If you want to know what you can pass to the `test_request_context` reference the `EnvironBuilder` definition; which can be found [here](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.14/test/#testing-api).

Comment: i get `requestcontext object has no attribute 'headers'`