# How do I call one Flask view from another one?

Tags: python, flask-login, flask

I have a JSON API in one blueprint module, and a web frontend in another one.

I would like to shave off a few AJAX requests the client JS code would have to make by embedding some of the JSON it'll need in the frontend view template, before sending it to the client, [like in this gist I found](https://gist.github.com/lost-theory/3005268).

**How do I call one Flask view from another Flask view?**

I could have called the view function directly, but `request` would correspond to the “outer” request, and this confuses the called API function. I've tried [using `test_request_context`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/testing/#other-testing-tricks) and it almost works but I can't figure out how to keep the authentication (I'm using Flask-Login).

Comment: I would take the logic that you are using to retrieve the data from the AJAX-called view and put it into another function. This function should not rely on authentication. Then, call that function from both views.

Comment: @Mark: That's what I'd normally have done, but the JSON functions rely on `request` object for generating pagination URLs and a few other things. I don't want to rewrite them all to explicitly pass `endpoint`, `request.args`, etc. I also *need* this pagination info in the generated JSON so the client knows how to fetch the next page. I agree it's not the most elegant solution, but it works best for me.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use a [Flask test client](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.test_client) for this:

```
client = app.test_client()
response = client.get('/your/url', headers=list(request.headers))
```

To keep the authentication with Flask-Login you need to pass your request's headers.

Thanks to [Chris McKinnel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/913026/chris-mckinnel) for [answering a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15281179/318359).

Comment: worked like a charm!
Also you could use `from flask import current_app` and use current_app.test_client()