# Test Coverage for Flask application doesnt work

Tags: python, flask, coverage.py, flask-testing

Hi want to test the "delete route" in my flask application in terminal I can see that the test is past and it said "test_user_delete (test_app.LayoutTestCase) ... ok" 
But when I open the cover page it still with red color which means doesn't cover it wold you please someone explain to me why and where I am doing wrong?

app.layout.view.py

[image]

test.py

```
            e1 = Users(name='admine2', email='admine2@gmail.com', age=25)
            e2 = Users(name='teste2', email='teste2@gmail.com', age=27)
            db.session.add_all([e1, e2])
            db.session.commit()
            u = Users.query.get(1)
            db.session.remove()
            db.session.delete(u)
            response = self.client.post('/delete/1',
            follow_redirects=True)
            self.assertTrue('admine2 is removed!', response.data)
```

view.py:

```
 @layout.route('/delete/<int:id>')
   def delete(id):
    """remove monkey"""
    user = Users.query.get_or_404(id)
    db.session.delete(user)
    db.session.commit()
    flash("{0} is removed!".format(user.name))
    return redirect(url_for("layout.user", page=1, sortby='normal'))
```

Comment: Try to change `self.assertTrue('delete done!', response.data)` by `self.assertEqual('delete done!', response.data)`: you are not testing anything now your `self.assertTrue()` sentence is always true. I'm not a Falsh expert but as far as I know `flash()` message are not in response but you can find somewhere else.

Comment: thnx @Micheled'Amico I got this error AssertionError: 'delete done!' != '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">\n<title>404 Not Found</title>\n<h1>Not Found</h1>\n<p>The requested URL was not found on the server.  If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>\n'

Comment: That means that you are not calling delete page (as coverage suggested). First test `response.code==200` (I'm guessing ...) to take sure to call it and the test db for user.

Comment: response = self.client.get(url_for('layout.delete%d'.format(e1.id) '))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200) @Micheled'Amico I'm not expert too :(( it should be like this?

Comment: Take a look to http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/testing/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15278285/setting-mocking-request-headers-for-flask-app-unit-test

Comment: well I read them before @Micheled'Amico But not really help

Comment: Try to use `app = flaskr.app.test_client()` and `response = app.get('layout.delete%d'.format(e1.id))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71495/discussion-between-lili-and-michele-damico).

Comment: Code coverage works fine. I think mistake associated with `login_required`. You can check it. Just comment `login_required` line. And re-run your test. If it helps, it means you should login before test.
Also, you can use `url_for(delete, id=9)` instead hard coded `/layout.delete/%d'.format(e1.id)` in tests too. It may helps you, because `url_for` guarantee correct url.

Answer (score -1):

I assume your setup-method sets `app.config['Testing'] = True`. Otherwise *Flask-login* is going to redirect you to your login-view.

**Edit** But this does not seem to be the issue here, as you get a 404-Error. If login-required was the problem is would be an unauthorized - 401 error. Instead I wrongfully assumed you registered your function with a 'DELETE' method, so my provided url_for statement was wrong.

You can find the flashed message in the session under the key `_flashes`. You could try:

```
with self.client as c:
    rv = self.client.get(url_for('delete', id=e1.id), follow_redirects=True)
    print rv.data
    with c.session_transaction() as session:
        self.assertTrue("delete done !." in session['_flashes'])
```

You also might want to take a look at [Flask Testing](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Testing/)