# Setting remote_addr in flask test_request_context

Tags: python, testing, flask

How can I set the `remote_addr` property in a flask test_request_context? This question: [Get IP Address when testing flask application through nosetests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872829/get-ip-address-when-testing-flask-application-through-nosetests) (and other, similar questions) explains how to do it using the get/post/whatever test client calls, but I'm not using those (in this case). Instead, I get a test_request_context and then call a function, thereby allowing me to test the functions that are called by my view functions individually.

Edit: to clarify, my testing code looks something like this:

```
with app.test_request_context():
    result=my_function_which_expects_to_be_called_from_a_request_context()
<check result however>
```

So at no point am I using a test client call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pass the same arguments to `test_request_context` as you would to `client.get`. Both set up the WSGI environment the same way internally.

```
with app.test_request_context(environ_base={'REMOTE_ADDR': '10.1.2.3'}):
```